# Sinatra + Mongo parallel requests

Tags: ruby, mongodb, sinatra

I'm developing a small script that does some data crunching. If I try to `ab -n10 -c1` (benckmark sending requests one after another), the requests take ~750ms. If instead I try `-c2` (send requests two at a time), the requests seem to take >2s. Here's how the code looks like:

```
get '/url/' do
    # ...
    # Images is a mongodb collection
    Images.find({'searchable_data.i' => {
        '$in' => color_codes
    }}).limit(5_000).each do |image|
        found_images << {
            :url => image['url'],
            :searchable_data => image['searchable_data'],
        }
    end
    # ...
```

From debugging I noticed that the requests to mongo fire at roughly the same time, and *return* at roughly the same time (but they take >2x the time they would if I ran them one at a time. Also, I've watched the cpu/memory usage on the mongo processes, and mongo doesn't even flinch). Here's how I connect to mongo:

```
configure do
    # ...
    server_connection = Mongo::Connection.new(db.host, db.port, :pool_size => 60)
    DB = server_connection.db(db_name)
    DB.authenticate(db.user, db.password) unless (db.user.nil? || db.user.nil?)
    Images = DB[:Images]
end
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong? I can't imagine the Mongodb driver being *that* bad.

Comment: It seems that if I run `thin start` instead of `ruby server.rb` or `thin start --threaded`, it works fine. But the question still holds..

Comment: I am confused, does `thin start --threaded` work?

Comment: I'm sorry, `thin start --threaded` and `ruby server.rb` make parallel requests very slow, as presented in the question. `thin start` is OK